# Reconstructing PostgreSQL database from data files

Tags: postgresql

You've heard the story, disk fails, no recent db backup, recovered files in disarray...

I've got a pg 9.1 database with a particular table I want to bring up to date.  In the postgres data/base/444444 directory are all the raw files with table and index data.  One particular table I can identify and it's files are as follows:

- [relfindnode]
- [relfindnode]_vm
- [relfindnode]_fsm

where [relfindnode] is the number corresponding to the table I want to reconstruct.

In the current out-of-date database the main [relfindnode] file is 16MB.

In my recovered files, I have found the corresponding [relfindnode] file and the _vm and _fsm files.  The main [relfindnode] file is 20MB, so I'm hopeful that this contains more upto-date data.

However, when I swap the files over and restart my machine (OS X) and I inspect the table, it has approximately the same number of records in it (not exactly the same).

**Question: is it possible just to swap out these files and expect it to work?  How else can I extract the data from the 20MB table file?  I've read the other threads here regarding constructing from raw data files.**

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried vacuuming the table? A larger file does not necessary mean that the table has more rows, it could just mean that the space is taken by the deleted but not yet vacuumed rows.

Comment: No I haven't vacuumed, and I see your point - however if the recovered files were more recent I should still see more rows right?

Comment: If the table is in general growing, then I'd indeed expect to see more rows.